# function that returns the maximum of one of several numbers and verifies whether the arguments are numbers

Tags: php, function

I am writing a function, with the name max_number, which returns the maximum of a number
numbers variable. If one of the arguments is not a number, then it returns false.
Using the is_numeric () function. But the function always returns false. Will I do something wrong?

The code and this:

```
<?php
function max_number()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    if( $args !== null && !is_numeric($args)){
        echo "false";       
    }
    else{
        echo "Maximo number is: " . max($args);
    }
}

max_number(1,2,3,4,5);
?>
```

Comment: `func_get_args()` returns an array! You expect it to return a numeric value

Comment: `$args` is an array, so the `is_numeric` check will be always false.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
function max_number()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    if( $args == null && !is_numeric($args)){
        echo "false";       
    }
    else{
        echo "Maximo number is: " . max($args);
    }
}

max_number(1,2,3,4,5);
?>
```

Comment: `!is_numeric($args)` is always `true` since `func_get_args()` returns an array ... your condition doesn't make any sense

Comment: You are absolutely right, in fact it makes no sense at all. The correct thing is if ($ args == null && is_numeric ($ args)), now it makes sense. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

In your code `$args` is an array and `is_numeric($args)` will always return `false`.

You need to check every element of `$args` individually.

```
<?php

function maxNum() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return ($args === array_filter($args,'is_numeric'))?max($args):false;
}

echo maxNum(1,2,3,4,5);          // 5

echo maxNum(1,"No!",3,4,5);     // false
```